# FosUserBundle Profile Edit form submission "The CSRF token is invalid. " error. Even though the _token value is present in the form

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I have overridden fosuserbundle's registration and profile edit forms but not their form handlers. The registration form is working as expected. But submitting the profile edit form has no effect. And when I traced where it is failing I found out that it's not passing the `$this->form->isValid()` in FOSUserBundle:ProfileFormHandler. When I var_dump the error it says "The CSRF token is invalid..." But my form is rendering a _token value.

Here's my code:

Overriden Profile Controller's editAction:

```
public function editAction()
    {
        $user = $this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
        if (!is_object($user) || !$user instanceof UserInterface) {
            throw new AccessDeniedException('This user does not have access to this section.');
        }

//        $form = $this->container->get('fos_user.profile.form');
        $form = $this->container->get('form.factory')->create('yyt_user_profile', $user);

        $formHandler = $this->container->get('fos_user.profile.form.handler');
        $process = $formHandler->process($user);

        if ($process) {
            $this->setFlash('fos_user_success', 'profile.flash.updated');

            return new RedirectResponse($this->getRedirectionUrl($user));
        }
        return $this->container->get('templating')->renderResponse(
            'UserBundle:Profile:edit.html.'.$this->container->getParameter('fos_user.template.engine'),
            array('form' => $form->createView(), 'active_page' => 'Profile')
        );
    }
```

My Profile Form Type:

```
namespace YYT\UserBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\ProfileFormType as BaseType;
use YYT\SharedBundle\Form\Type\AddressType;

class ProfileFormType extends BaseType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        parent::buildForm($builder, $options);

        $builder->add('fullName')
            ->add('address', new AddressType(), array('label' => false))

        ;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'yyt_user_profile';
    }
}
```

My service.yml

```
services:
  yyt_user.registration.form.type:
          class: YYT\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType
          arguments: [%fos_user.model.user.class%]
          tags:
              - { name: form.type, alias: yyt_user_registration }
  yyt_user.profile.form.type:
          class: YYT\UserBundle\Form\Type\ProfileFormType
          arguments: [%fos_user.model.user.class%]
          tags:
              - { name: form.type, alias: yyt_user_profile }
```

The app/config/config.yml

```
...
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: YYT\UserBundle\Entity\User
    registration:
        form:
            type: yyt_user_registration
    profile:
        form:
            type: yyt_user_profile
```

My profile form type:

And my overriding edit_content.html.twig:

```
<form action="{{ path('fos_user_profile_edit') }}" {{ form_enctype(form) }} method="POST" class="fos_user_profile_edit">
    <div class="col-md-7">
        <div class="form-group row">
            {{ form_row(form.fullName) }}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            {{ form_row(form.username) }}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            {{ form_row(form.email) }}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            {{ form_row(form.address.addrTelephone) }}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            {{ form_row(form.address.addrMobile) }}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            {{ form_row(form.address.addrSubCity) }}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            {{ form_row(form.current_password) }}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="{{ 'profile.edit.submit'|trans({}, 'FOSUserBundle') }}" />
    </div>
    {{ form_end(form, { "render_rest":false}) }}
```

What did I miss here?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

```
  {{ form_end(form, { "render_rest":false}) }}
```

You didn't render field with csrf token. Remove `"render_rest":false` or add csrf token  manually `<input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token('intention') }}">`

Comment: I have tried both ways you recommended but there's no change. But I noticed the {{ form_end(form) }} renders this field: <input type="hidden" id="yyt_user_profile__token" name="yyt_user_profile[_token]" value="7cxTfwCINRHqx6flg23e9hc1WUipxF2yTnois3fBwcY">

And that is different from the name of the hidden input you posted above. In case this info helps.